# Generate Data Change Scripts from VSTS Database Edition

Tags: database, version-control, deployment

I'm using the GDR release of VSTS Database edition source control the DB and generate deployment scripts.  It works pretty well but the problem is that it only seems to handle scripting and deploying the schema.  It stops short of handling scripting and deployment of the actual data itself (i.e. the lookup and standing data which also deployed with the DB).

I know it's easy enough to write the deployment scripts by hand, but is this what every one does?  Is there a recommended way of deploying data with the VSTS deployment engine?  Is there some tooling that help with this - I don't mean a full product like SQLCompare, just something that fills the gap with VSTS DB.

Thanks in advance.

Kaneda

Answer (score 2):

The VSTS: DB best practices blog [advocates using post-deployment scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/bahill/archive/2009/04/01/maintaining-and-synchronizing-your-reference-data.aspx) to insert reference data into temporary tables, then update the target tables based on the delta (ie update x inner join temp where x.something <> temp.something)

There's some [suggestions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/2044354a-5dbc-44e8-b9c1-9371f27420fd) [floating](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/156e3da3-f59b-4ded-a7b8-9027104ca0ff/) around that this might make a powertool, and at least one MVP has [written a tool to generate those scripts](http://leon.mvps.org/StaticData/).

(NB: I haven't tried this - I only just found out about it myself)

Personally I would still stick with RedGate if I had any choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

GDR comes with a data comparison engine, but as far as I've been able to tell so far a data comparison can't even be *stored* in a project (let alone be properly supported by it) - so it's pretty ad-hoc. Unlike a Schema Compare, there is no File \ Save As.

The comparison engine can be [automated via DDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/psirr/archive/2008/11/22/data-compare-dte-commands.aspx) but that's automation within the Visual Studio IDE, and not really suitable for some kind of scripted installation process. As much as anything there's no way I could see to specify which tables to include in the comparison (since all you get to do via DDE is open the wizard for the user to select)

Alternatively all the functionality appears to reside in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.DataPackage.dll , but since the API documentation hasn't been written yet (the help doco that comes with GDR is full of errors as it is) it's going to be a bit of a hit-and-miss adventure to work out where to start.

As someone who's used RedGate's SqlCompare, SqlDataCompare and their respective APIs to do this before, much of the GDR functionality seems a bit half-baked to me.

What I will probably do this time round is sync the data with a SSIS package (export to CSV at build time / import from CSV at install time), but I'd far rather be using the SqlDataCompare API (or SqlPackager) right now.